# Convert single channle image to 3 channel image C++ / OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

Im using openCV C++

Im need to convert a single channel image to 3 channels image. So i can use this: `cvCvtColor(result,gray,CV_BGR2GRAY);`

I cannot do that because the result img is a single channel image. Any ideas?

Answer (score 17):

You should use `CV_GRAY2BGR` instead of `CV_BGR2GRAY`.

Comment: that gives me the same error:Bad number of channels (Incorrect number of channels for this conversion code) in cvCvtColor

Comment: You also must change order of the first two arguments: cvCvtColor(gray, result, CV_GRAY2BGR). Read docs carefully: void cvCvtColor(const CvArr* src, CvArr* dst, int code);

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
CvSize dim = cvSize(int width, int height);
IplImage* dst = cvCreateImage( dim, 8, 3 );
IplImage* gray = cvCreateImage(dim, 8, 1);
// Load the gray scale image
cvMerge(gray , NULL, NULL, NULL, dst);
cvShowImage("gray",gray);
cvShowImage("dst",dst);
cvWaitKey(0);
```

Both dst and gray must have their data types same. You cant simply merge a float in a uint matrix. You will have to use cvScale for that.

Comment: Be careful with IplImage, it is now deprecated.

Answer (score 7):

I checked **cvtColor** in OpenCV reference book, and found this:

> C++:void **cvtColor**(InputArray **src**, OutputArray **dst**, int **code**, int **dstCn**=0 )
>
> > **dstCn** – Number of channels in the destination image. If the parameter is 0, the number of the channels is derived automatically from src and code .

I have used

```
cvtColor(src,gray,CV_BGR2GRAY,1);
```

to convert a 3-channels Mat to 1-channels, and it worked. So changing **dstCn** to 3 might work for you :)

Answer (score 3):

Try merging gray,gray,gray into a BGR.

Comment: I don't know How? `cvMerge(grey, grey, grey, NULL, final);` not working.

Comment: @rptwsthi: You don't use cvMerge function here. Try some matrix manipulation instead. The point is to replicate 2 identical matrices to the original gray one, and store them as if there are 3 channels.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a vector of the same channel, then merge them, like as follows:

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> copies{mat,mat,mat};  
cv::merge(copies,mat);
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO:
If input is gray, then output would be gray. The best you can get is a colored distributed image based on pixel data say `(110, 110, 110)` for pixel data of `110`, and not the true colored image